# Change enum's displayed value in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, enums

I have DataGridView binded to list of objects with many different types of values(ints, DateTime, strings and enums). For most of types displayed values are okay, but not for enums. I'd like to display them in DataGridView with custom names(from `XmlEnumAttribute`, to be specific, but I know how to get the string from it). I know I'd wrap the object in another object which contained strings rather than enums, but I don't want to do this this way.

So, in example: when enum's value is `GeneralSurgery`, I'd like it to be displayed in `DataGridView` as `General surgery`, `Item3060Minutes` as `30-60 minutes` etc.

Comment: You could use the `Description` attribute to provide the better name per enum value, or harvest them all if it is a Combo column.

Comment: @Plutonix it doesn't change the way DataGridView displays the enum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the CellFormatting event of DataGridview to modify the displayed value:

```
private void  dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].name=="MyEnumColumnName")
    { 
       MyEnumType enumValue = (MyEnumType)e.value ;
       string enumstring = ... ; // convert here the enum to displayed string 
       e.Value = enumstring ;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `DataGridView` will use a `TypeConverter` if one is assigned.  This `PetTypeConverter` will return the enum's `Description`.

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(PetTypeConverter))]
public enum PetType
{
    [Description("Kitty-cat")]Feline,
    [Description("doggie")]Canine,
    [Description("scary!")]Dragon,
    [Description("Extra-Terra")]Alien
}

class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public PetType Species { get; set; }

    public Pet(string name, PetType p)
    {
        Name = name;
        Species = p;
    }
}

public class PetTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext 
            context, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(destinationType, typeof(string)))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
            CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(destinationType, typeof(string))) {
            FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
            DescriptionAttribute[] attr = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            if (attr.Length > 0) {
                return attr[0].Description;
            } else {
                return value.ToString();
            }
        }

        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

Note that if that property can be edited in the DGV that you will need to also provide the means to convert the descriptions back into valid enum values.  Presumably, this would be a Combo column for which you would provide all the Descriptions, so you'd just have to look it up.

Result:

[image]

If the `enum` is used elsewhere, you might want to move `PetTypeConverter` to the property so only that usage of `PetType` is converted.

Comment: "you might want to move PetTypeConverter to the property so only that usage of PetType is converted." - is there a way to move a more-generic `EnumTypeConverter` to the `DataGridView` itself so the backing model doesn't have to be contaminated with loads of copies of the same attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but to get the string value of an enum use

```
Enum.GetName(typeof(EnumType), enumVal);
```

You're still going to have to format the string though

Answer (score 0):

Because your `DataGridView` is binded to the `List` of your custom type.
One of the approaches can be add a readonly property which return a value of your attribute(`XmlEnumAttribute`)

```
public string EnumValueDescription
{
    get { return this.GetAttributeOfSelectedEnumValue(); }
}
```

Then bind this value to the column of `DataGridValue`

Answer (score 0):

As @Graffito said you should use the cellFormatting event to handle a different display for your enum column. You can then use reflection to get the attributes of the current enum's value and then use that attributes description

```
private void  dataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "MyEnumColumn")
    { 
       SomeEnum enumValue = (SomeEnum)e.value ;
       e.Value = ((XmlEnumAttribute)typeof(SomeEnum).GetMember(enumValue.ToString()).FirstOrDefault().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlEnumAttribute)).FirstOrDefault()).Description ;
     }
}
```